# Energy accounts fraudulently opened in Texas

Tags: united-states, scams, fraud

I don't understand this scam. My wife had several energy utility accounts opened in Texas. They were all opened at the same time, for different addresses, and with different energy companies. They charged a few hundred dollars each. The accounts were all closed after two months, presumably because the bills were not paid.

Did multiple people participate in this scam; because the accounts were for electricity at different addresses?

Did the people move immediately after? That seems like a lot of work for a few hundred dollars in utilities.

Are people somehow reselling the energy? I know Texas has a different structure for their energy grid.

I only found one news report about this, also in Texas, from *KPRC Investigates Texas*.

We do not live in Texas, so it would be hard to go knock on doors to try to find out more.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It might be just one step in a wider identity fraud. If someone can successfully open a utility account it might give them a proof of address, which can be used to open other accounts. It's possible someone is trying to build a chain of trust and work up to a bigger goal such as a bank account, credit card, mail redirection etc.

Comment: But the real problem is how lax these companies are to check the data when opening an account.

Answer (score 17):

> Did the people move immediately after? That seems like a lot of work for a few hundred dollars in utilities.

Maybe. Squatting in empty houses, or just opening new utility accounts every couple of months under a different stolen identity can save the criminal a bunch of money. It could also involve people living there who might themselves be scammed (e.g.: someone offers them a place with "utilities included" that they don't even own - I had this happen with my of my rental properties once).

Put a freeze on your credit reports, track them often, and make sure to notify any company that opens a new line of credit that you're not aware of. Also worth putting a fraud alert with your phone number so that every credit check will trigger a phone call to you for confirmation. Sometimes utilities and such don't actually do credit checks, but will report delinquencies - that may require some more work to clean up.